# PySpark escape backslash and delimiter when reading csv

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am attempting to read a CSV in PySpark where my delimiter is a "|", but there are some columns that have a "\|" as part of the value in the cell.

```
CSV Data:
a|b|c|this should be \| one column
```

```
some_df = spark.read.csv(file, sep="|", quote="")
some_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+----------------+-----------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|             _c3|        _c4|
+---+---+---+----------------+-----------+
| a | b | c |this should be \| one column|
+---+---+---+----------------+-----------+
```

Expected:

```
+---+---+---+---------------------------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|                        _c3|
+---+---+---+---------------------------+
| a | b | c |this should be \ one column|
+---+---+---+---------------------------+
```

Comment: The values with `|` in should be double-quoted to be conforming CSV, are you in control of input data formatting?

Comment: I am not in control of the input data. I have thousands of CSV files formatted like this. The columns with the issues always have a "\|"

Comment: you can do one thing, read as RDD and remove that char and convert to DataFram

Comment: @Nikk, I've tried that option but haven't been successful. Here is the code I've been attempting to use: ```myfile = sc.textFile("test.txt")
myfile2 = myfile.map(lambda x: [re.sub("\\\|", "", x)])
myfile2.toDF().show()``` However, this does not yield the expected output, everything gets treated as one column and does not merge the third and fourth columns. I expected the regex to remove the "\|" but it did not

Comment: Stick an `r` at the front of the regex, so `re.sub(r"\\\|", "", x)` ... should be better ...

Comment: @wobr, that seems to remove the delimiter issue I was having. Now how can I read the RDD to a dataframe so it is separating the columns based on the delimiter "|"? Currently when I use ```toDF()``` all the items are in one column with the delimiter? I attempted a ```map(lambda y: y.split("|"))``` but I receive a ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'```

Comment: @Samer Please check my answer for your issue in rdd to toDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> rdd  = sc.textFile("/.../file.csv")
>>> rdd.collect()
['a|b|c|this should be \\| one column']

>>> rdd1  = rdd.map(lambda x: x.replace("\\|", ""))
>>> rdd1.collect()
['a|b|c|this should be  one column']

>>> df = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x.split("|"))).map(lambda a : (a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])).toDF(('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'))
>>> df.show(10,False)
+----+----+----+--------------------------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4                      |
+----+----+----+--------------------------+
|a   |b   |c   |this should be  one column|
+----+----+----+--------------------------+
```

Comment: that worked! Can you explain how the ```rdd.collect()``` is working in this example? I'm a bit new to Spark and am not familiar as to how ```collect()``` works.

Comment: you don't need to use collect() in your actual code, collect() in function that collect all RDD data and sent to driver, I have use to display value that contain in RDD just to show you.

Comment: What if number of columns are dynamic?