# How to escape delimiter inside the value

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, pyspark

I am facing an issue with escaping the delimiter inside the value. My code reads a PSV file. Of late I am getting the delimiter `|` (with the escape character `\`) in one of the columns value. Because of this issue, records are being dropped. Please see the issue below.

Records

```
abcd|1234|222\|3344|count|33 

abcd|1234|111\|5566|count|44
```

In this file the delimiter is `|` and valid values for 3rd column is `222|3344` and `111|5566` respectively.

I am using the following syntax to read the file.

````
df_input=spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|")..option("escape", "\\").load(var_files_path +"/*.psv" , schema=input_schema)```

When I read, a few records were skipped because of the delimiter inside the value. Can you please guide me to solve this issue. TIA.
````

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pyspark uses Python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), then the default `quotechar` is `"`, which gives a clue about how Excel defined quoting in csv: Surround a value string with the quote character. It's not an escape sequence to prefix a single character.

Try this in a Python console:

```py
>>> import csv
>>> import io

>>> i = io.StringIO('abcd|1234|"222|3344"|count|33')
>>> r = csv.reader(i, delimiter='|')
>>> r.__next__()
['abcd', '1234', '222|3344', 'count', '33']

>>> i = io.StringIO(r'abcd|1234|\222|3344\|count|33')
>>> r = csv.reader(i, delimiter='|', quotechar='\\')
>>> r.__next__()
['abcd', '1234', '222|3344', 'count', '33']
```

The PSV format is typically used for cases where the pipe character would not appear in the data, so no quoting would be needed. Maybe tab-separated values (TSV) would be easier in your case.

Answer (score -1):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831393/pyspark-escape-backslash-and-delimiter-when-reading-csv) used rdd

```
rdd1  = rdd.map(lambda x: x.replace("\\|", ""))
```

I myself has used rdd with Python regex

```
import re
raw_string = r"(\\\|)"
rdd_cleaned = rdd.map(lambda x: re.sub(raw_string, "", x))
```